# Unity edit list size when its used in update function

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Let's say i have a update function like that:

```
for (int i = 0; i < players.Count; i++)
{
     Debug.Log(players[i].name);
}
```

This list is being used in Update() so if i remove any of list items from another script/function it will just throw a error because list size is changed while loop is going on. How do i fix this?

Comment: No it won't .. the loop is completely run and then another code is run that can add/remove elements. Except, you have a different thread accessing that list .. in that case you should `lock` either way. The other only way how this throws the error is by removing/adding elements from within that loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug bug pops up everywhere in programming where you are working with some collection that might modify the collection you are working with.

In my experience there are two options:

1. Take a copy of the collection and work with the copy, if it is okay to show out of date information.
2. Handle any errors that occur from the collection being modified and restart your logic using the latest collection.

Option 1: Work with a copy:

Before accessing the collection, take a copy of what is in memory. For example, use`.ToList()` or `.ToArray()`

```cs
var playersCopy = players.ToList();
for (int i = 0; i < playersCopy .Count; i++)
{
  Debug.Log(playersCopy [i].name);
}
```

Using this approach you have a copy in memory that cannot be modified, even thought that copy can possible be stale or out of date.

2). If using a stale copy is not acceptable, then you need to handle an exceptions that occur from the collection being modified while you are iterating through it.

For example, you can put access to the collection inside of a `try catch` and retry your logic if the collection was modified.

```cs
bool success = false;
while(!success)
{
    try {
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < players.Count; i++)
        {
             Debug.Log(players[i].name);
        }
        success=true; // loop completed without error
    }
    catch { }
}
```

Note the later is a simplified example and depending on your circumstance you might want to do different actions with the caught error.

Also note, that latter is not recommended if there are side effects For example, `Debug.Log` might already have printed out a stale player.

This has its own solutions, EG: Save the player names to a list first and then print out the in memory list or again use custom logic (for example, track which players are no longer in the list and print a message saying they left and continue with the rest of the list).

Still the approach is the same, use an in memory copy or detect the changes in real time and handle them.

Comment: Thank you. I know these solutions but i just thought there may be a easy way to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, based on the information you supplied, this won't throw an error.

In a standard scenario, the Update method will be called and complete before the next Update method on the following script is called. The main Unity worker thread isn't being called from anywhere else, so one script wouldn't interrupt an Update method call mid function.

Now, if you had said you were using co-routines, and had yielded during a 'foreach' loop, then in that case, you might have a scenario whereby the enumerator threw an error, because you could have modified the underlying enumerable (players) from somewhere else in this script, or another.

Another way to put it, this is bad:

```
public class Base : MonoBehaviour
{
    List<int> list;

    void Start ( )
    {
        list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        StartCoroutine ( ForEachTest ( ) );
        list.Add ( 5 );
    }

    IEnumerator ForEachTest ( )
    {
        foreach ( var item in list )
        {
            Debug.Log ( $"Item value : {item}" );
            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Would result in:

> InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration
> operation may not execute.

If you take a look at the code for the enumerator, you can see why an Exception is thrown.

```
public bool MoveNext()
{
    List<T> list = this.list;
    if (version == list._version && (uint)index < (uint)list._size)
    {
        current = list._items[index];
        index++;
        return true;
    }
    return MoveNextRare();
}


private bool MoveNextRare()
{
    if (version != list._version)
    {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource.InvalidOperation_EnumFailedVersion);
    }
    index = list._size + 1;
    current = default(T);
    return false;
}
```

When a List (as suggested by your use of Count, not Length) is modified, the enumerator sees that the collection's version has been modified, which invalidates the enumerator.

Note, that if you don't use an enumerator, and simply use a for loop that is checking the list's Count property, you won't run into this problem.

Comment: I don't think this has anything specifically to do with Unity. Instead, there is some collection that references players and while iterating the collection it is modified. This is more of a general programming issue, afaik.